# I can't update form fields values on my custom shipping method Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I really hope someone can help me, cause i'm running out of ideas.

I made this custom shipping methon on Woocommerce, copying and pasting from the website documentation and other StakO topics.
Everything seems to be okay, apart of when i try to update my only one field called "Store Address", it doesn't works and values are not updated.

Here's the code. Thanks to everyone

```
if ( ! defined( 'WPINC' ) ) {
   die;
}

if ( in_array( 'woocommerce/woocommerce.php', apply_filters( 'active_plugins', get_option( 'active_plugins' ) ) ) ) {

   function pickupinstore_shipping_method() {
       if ( ! class_exists( 'PickupInStore_Shipping_Method' ) ) {
           class PickupInStore_Shipping_Method extends WC_Shipping_Method {
               /**
                * Constructor for your shipping class
                *
                * @access public
                * @return void
                */
               public function __construct( $instance_id = 0 ) {
                   $this->id                 = 'pickupinstore'; 
                   $this->instance_id  = absint( $instance_id );
                   $this->method_title       = __( 'Pickup in Store', 'pickupinstore' );  
                   $this->method_description = __( 'Custom Shipping Method - Pickup in Store', 'pickupinstore' ); 

                   $this->supports              = array(
                       'shipping-zones',
                       'instance-settings',
                       'instance-settings-modal',
                   );

                   
                   $this->init();

                   $this->title = isset( $this->settings['title'] ) ? "Ritiro in Negozio | ".$this->settings['title'].": GRATIS" : __( 'Pickup in Store', 'pickupinstore' );                }

               /**
                * Init your settings
                *
                * @access public
                * @return void
                */
               function init() {
                   // Load the settings API
                   $this->init_form_fields(); 
                   $this->init_settings(); 

                   // Save settings in admin if you have any defined
                   add_action( 'woocommerce_update_options_shipping_' . $this->id, array( $this, 'process_admin_options' ) );
               }

               /**
                * Define settings field for this shipping
                * @return void 
                */
               function init_form_fields() { 

                   $this->form_fields = array(
                                 
                       'title' => array(
                          'title' => __( 'Ritiro in Negozio', 'pickupinstore' ),
                            'type' => 'text',
                            'description' => __( 'Store Address', 'pickupinstore' ),
                            'default' => __( '197, Brooklyn Road', 'New York' ),
                            'desc_tip'    => true,
                       ),    
                   );
               }


               /**
                * This function is used to calculate the shipping cost. Within this function we can check for weights, dimensions and other parameters.
                *
                * @access public
                * @param mixed $package
                * @return void
                */

               public function calculate_shipping( $package = array() ) {
                   
                   $cost = 0;
                   $this->add_rate( array(
                       'id' => $this->id,
                       'label'   => $this->title,
                       'cost' => $cost
                   ) );              

               }
           }
       }
   }
   add_action( 'woocommerce_shipping_init', 'pickupinstore_shipping_method' );

   function add_pickupinstore_shipping_method( $methods ) {
       $methods['pickupinstore'] = 'PickupInStore_Shipping_Method';
       return $methods;
   }

   add_filter( 'woocommerce_shipping_methods', 'add_pickupinstore_shipping_method' );

}
```

---

**Edit:**

I tried using @docker code, but when I save changes nothing compares in the title section (backend). Otherwise the form field seems to be saved, but as you can see, not diplayed.

[image]

In front end, it displays the name of the custom shipping method instead of the title I save.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the `$this->title` definition to the `init()` method and use `$this->get_option()` instead of `$this->settings`.

```php
function init() {
   // Load the settings API
   $this->init_form_fields();
   $this->init_settings();

   $this->title = null != $this->get_option('title') ? "Ritiro in Negozio | " . $this->get_option('title') . ": GRATIS" : __( 'Pickup in Store', 'pickupinstore' );

   // Save settings in admin if you have any defined
   add_action( 'woocommerce_update_options_shipping_' . $this->id, array( $this, 'process_admin_options' ) );

}
```

Additionally in the `init_form_fields()` method you should use `$this->instance_form_fields`.

```php
function init_form_fields() {

   $this->instance_form_fields = array(

       'title' => array(
          'title' => __( 'Ritiro in Negozio', 'pickupinstore' ),
            'type' => 'text',
            'description' => __( 'Store Address', 'pickupinstore' ),
            'default' => __( '197, Brooklyn Road', 'New York' ),
            'desc_tip'    => true,
       ),
   );
}
```

In some cases you may need the `get_instance_from_fields()` method but I have a working solution without it:

```php
    /**
     * Get setting form fields for instances of this shipping method within zones.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function get_instance_form_fields() {
        return parent::get_instance_form_fields();
    }
```

**EDIT:**
This is the full working code:

```php
<?php
/**
* Plugin Name: Pickup in Store
* Plugin URI: https://www.perspectiveweb.it/
* Description: Pickup in store - Custom Shipping Method
* Version: 1.0.0
* Author: Perspective Web
* Author URI: https://www.perspectiveweb.it/
* License: GPL-3.0+
* License URI: http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-3.0.html
* Domain Path: /lang
* Text Domain: perspectiveweb
*/

if ( ! defined( 'WPINC' ) ) {
   die;
}

if ( in_array( 'woocommerce/woocommerce.php', apply_filters( 'active_plugins', get_option( 'active_plugins' ) ) ) ) {

   function pickupinstore_shipping_method() {
       if ( ! class_exists( 'PickupInStore_Shipping_Method' ) ) {
           class PickupInStore_Shipping_Method extends WC_Shipping_Method {
               /**
                * Constructor for your shipping class
                *
                * @access public
                * @return void
                */
               public function __construct( $instance_id = 0 ) {
                   $this->id                 = 'pickupinstore'; 
                   $this->instance_id  = absint( $instance_id );
                   $this->method_title       = __( 'Pickup in Store', 'pickupinstore' );  
                   $this->method_description = __( 'Custom Shipping Method - Pickup in Store', 'pickupinstore' ); 

                   $this->supports              = array(
                       'shipping-zones',
                       'instance-settings',
                       'instance-settings-modal',
                   );


                   $this->init();
              }

               /**
                * Init your settings
                *
                * @access public
                * @return void
                */
               public function init() {
                 // Load the settings API
                 $this->init_form_fields();
                 $this->init_settings();

                 $this->title = null != $this->get_option('title') ? "Ritiro in Negozio | " . $this->get_option('title') . ": GRATIS" : __( 'Pickup in Store', 'pickupinstore' );

                 // Save settings in admin if you have any defined
                 add_action( 'woocommerce_update_options_shipping_' . $this->id, array( $this, 'process_admin_options' ) );

               }

               /**
                * Define settings field for this shipping
                * @return void
                */
              public function init_form_fields() {

                 $this->instance_form_fields = array(

                     'title' => array(
                        'title' => __( 'Ritiro in Negozio', 'pickupinstore' ),
                          'type' => 'text',
                          'description' => __( 'Store Address', 'pickupinstore' ),
                          'default' => __( '197, Brooklyn Road', 'New York' ),
                          'desc_tip'    => true,
                     ),
                 );
              }


               /**
                * This function is used to calculate the shipping cost. Within this function we can check for weights, dimensions and other parameters.
                *
                * @access public
                * @param mixed $package
                * @return void
                */

               public function calculate_shipping( $package = array() ) {
                   $cost = 0;
                   $this->add_rate( array(
                       'id' => $this->id,
                       'label'   => $this->title,
                       'cost' => $cost
                   ) );

               }
           }
       }
   }
   add_action( 'woocommerce_shipping_init', 'pickupinstore_shipping_method' );

   function add_pickupinstore_shipping_method( $methods ) {
       $methods['pickupinstore'] = 'PickupInStore_Shipping_Method';
       return $methods;
   }

   add_filter( 'woocommerce_shipping_methods', 'add_pickupinstore_shipping_method' );

}
```

Comment: Hi @docker, i've updated my code, and it seems not to work again. I've made an edit where i show what happens when i use your changes. Any advice? Thanks

Comment: Hi @giovinazzo17 I've edited my answer to include the whole code.

Comment: Thank you so much. It works. I hope this can save other's people time!

Comment: Hi @giovinazzo17, you are most welcome. Please update your question's 'Edit section' since my suggestions are working.
The only other difference was this:

`$this->title = null != $this->get_option('title') ? "Ritiro in Negozio | " . $this->get_option('title') . ": GRATIS" : __( 'Pickup in Store', 'pickupinstore' );
`